# Invoking method in a particular thread while processing in another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm starting a long running task like that:

```
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

In *LongRunningMethod* I'm calling third party methods which are raising events. That events contain data that I need to add to my data table:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(e.Data);
```

The trouble is, that the *dataTable* can be associated with some view that requires calling *Invoke* method, but I don't want to add any references to interfaces, that implement *Invoke* like method.

I would like to do something like that:

```
originalThread.Invoke(() => dataTable.Rows.Add(e.Data));
```

What are the best options to achieve that goal?

Comment: What kind (WinForms, WPF, ...) of Application?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Any type of presentation layer should be abble to connect to my data source (here _dataTable_) but some of them will throw an exception if rows will be added in different thread. That is the problem.

Comment: You can't "break into a Thread", you can only push (Invoke) a method to a Message queue , ie WPF Dispatcher or WinForms app. You will need a helper class.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Is there no possibility to interrupt the original thread, save its context, then perform an action in it and finally restore it from interruption point?

Comment: @yBee: all thsi stuff about save context/do/restore context does .NET framework under the hood, why just not passing in a Task original (I believe UI) thread context and then just invoke suign it's Dispatcher?

Comment: why do you use a shared datatable to propagate the results? Why don't you define an event to report results from your datasource (which the caller can marshal to UI thread) or return a complete dataTable at the end of the operation?

Comment: @Firo: I can't return complete data table at the end because I want user to see computed results as soon as possible. About sending events with data, that isn't bad idea, but it requires more effort in presentations synchronization. Now I have one shared data source.

Comment: @sll: You're right. There is a _SynchronizationContext.Current_ that I can store as _originalSynchronizationContext_ and then in task I can call `originalSynchronizationContext.Post(state => dataTable.Rows.Add(e.Data), null);`. It doesn't require any additional effort from presentation. I think that will meet my requirements.

Comment: Why don't you use BackgroundWorker? It provides sincronization between threads automatically.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz: BackgroundWorker is closely related to component model and I'm not sure whether I should use it in my scenario. Besides, I would like to use TAP instead EAP.

Comment: And also the BackgroundWorker uses ThreadPool under the hood and my methods are the long running ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By aggregating helpful comments I can produce an answer.

According to [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman), there is no possibility to interrupt original thread, store its context, perform some action and then restore its previous context and run further.

There are specific solutions for target presentation layers like [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) in WinForms and [Dispatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) in WPF.

I believe that for my scenario the suggestion from [sll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/485076/sll) works best. I can use [SynchronizationContext Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) and its [Post Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx). Below is an example:

```
originalSynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
task = Task.Factory.StartNew(LongRunningMethod, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

In parallel LongRunningMethod:

```
originalSynchronizationContext.Post(state => dataTable.Rows.Add(e.Data), null);
```